# Can't wrap file in form-data and POST to express endpoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, fetch, form-data

I have 2 desires. 1. I want to post an mp3 file using fetch. 2. To do this I , assume, I want to wrap it in a form-data obj. I can successfully store this mp3 file in my react state. The problem is that when I try and retrieve that file using this.state.myFile and append that file to a key and then console.log the formData variable, its empty (I am assuming because it takes a while to assign the 12mb mp3 file and js just goes right to the next line and tries to log it before the assignment actually finishes). Anyway, if I am able to do this, I can just set the fetch body: myFormDataVar and set the appropriate headers right?

ex mp3 file to send (its ~13mb):

File {name: "tranceLead2.mp3", lastModified: 1555115855246, lastModifiedDate: Fri Apr 12 2019 19:37:35 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 12851270, …}

I appreciate the help.
Below is my client-side code that is inside a function:

```
let form_data = new FormData();

// NOT working for me
form_data.append("title", this.state.title); //from react state
form_data.append("track", this.state.file);  //from react state
// NOT working for me

console.log(form_data); // '{}' <-- output

fetch('http://localhost:8080/tracks', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: form_data,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }).then(res => {
            if (res.status !== 200 && res.status !== 201) {
                console.log("Did not send...");
                throw new Error("Failed...");
            }
            console.log("Status: " + res.status);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

[FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) is a complex object that doesn't serialize it's entries when you log an instance to console.

All you will see are the prototype methods. To access what's in it you need to use the API methods like `values()` , `get()`, `entries()` etc, some of which return iterables. The methods and returns are  similar to `Map`

```js
const f = new FormData()

f.append('foo', 'bar');
f.append('arr', JSON.stringify([1,2,3]))

console.log('get:', f.get('foo'));
console.log('entries:', [...f.entries()]);
console.log('values:', [...f.values()]);
```